# Strange unclickable icon on desktop

Tags: big-sur, desktop

This icon is on my desktop. Can't click it or remove it.
I tried changing the desktop background but it didn't remove it.
Any idea what is it and how I can remove it ? Cheers

[image]

Comment: That's not a very good picture! Is there a name under the icon? Have you used **Terminal** to look at it? If you reboot, is it still there?

Comment: You can try via Terminal Application this command : ``ls -la ~/Desktop``. This will give you a list of the Desktop Files.

Comment: How long has it been there? Can you remember any correlation between when it appeared and which apps you were running? Did your computer crash and then it appeared? The icon itself is from Preview app (photograph & loupe) so it is/was ostensibly an image format, though anything is possible.

Comment: Well... it disappeared on its own, without even restarting or killing a program. There was no name under the icon, and it was on far bottom left of my screen, I couldn't get a better screenshot really. I had tried the ls command but nothing showed up. Really weird !